# Linux process performance monitoring agent

Tags: linux, performance, process, monitoring

Hi Stackoverflow community,

For our tool we're trying to build a agent to remotely monitor linux processes, the resources they use, i/o info and tcp/ip connectivity. This is to gather these metrics and send them over to the server using [log4](http://logging.apache.org). We're doing this in windows use wmi and log4net and looking to do the same in linux.

In essence, doing what top, lsof -i and iostat do then sending it to the central server.

Have seen some initiatives at:

- lttng
- munin monitoring
- systemtap
- opennms
- godrb.com
- mcollective
- http://bitbucket.org/chrismiles/psi/wiki/Home

Looking at the source code of top, it directly queries /proc whereas lttng needs to install kernel  modules. Bearing in mind, the end use is for enterprise systems, we would like to keep it as close to the kernel as possible without needing to add new modules.

Our goal is to monitor what each process on the box uses (cpu/mem/io etc), any process info (eg version) and where it connects tcp source and destination and send this to the server using log4. Happy for it to be in any language C/php/python/ruby etc

Do you have any suggestions?

Bill

Comment: Whatever you do – never run tcpdump without any filters in an ssh session ;)

Comment: Jonas :) wouldn't imagine doing that! Still have to keep some cpu for the server to do its thing!

Comment: If you're looking for cross-platform compatibility, don't rely on the existence of /proc.  FreeBSD and OSX systems don't have a proc filesystem mounted by default.  Have a look at [FreeBSD's top source](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/usr.bin/top/) to see how things work over there.

Comment: Only looking at Linux for now. Might need Solaris and six further down the line

Comment: sorry autocorrect typo, six=AIX

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking? What's wrong with the tools listed? What is wrong with just dumping the output of all the /proc files you care about? Side note: StackOverflow has [their own tool](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/11/announcing-bosun-our-new-open-source-monitoring-alerting-system/).

Answer (score 0):

"In essence, doing what top, lsof -i and iostat do then sending it to the central server"

Try **[SeaLion](http://sealion.com)**. Its exactly what you want. It will also give you the flexibility to add more commands as and when your monitoring requirements change or increase. You wouldn't have to look for other tools. It is lesser known but works very easily; simple setup and a great timeline to view the past data in.

Comment: This looks good, any idea about a similar app, that is able to do it for a single process? Eg wrap the process and sample it's behavior? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For true enterprise monitoring, I would look at Megamon (http://www.megamon.com)